# Strange Neo4j Cypher Aggregator behaviour with WITH Clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Below query is working fine :

```
Match (x1:A) with x1 
optional Match (x1)-[:A_B]-(x2:B) 
with x1 ,count(x2) as x3 
where x1.foo= 'bar' and (x3 = 1) 
return DISTINCT x1 as A 
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 10
```

But this query is giving wrong output

```
Match (x1:A) with x1 
optional Match (x1)-[:A_B]-(x2:B) 
with x1 ,x2, count(x2) as x3 
where x1.foo= 'bar' and (x3 = 1) 
return DISTINCT x1 as A 
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not incorrect, this is just a misunderstanding of how implicit grouping keys work when you're aggregating in Cypher.

When aggregating, the non-aggregation terms becomes the grouping key, which is the context for what you are aggregating over.

The key differences are in your WITH clause when you're aggregating. In the first query you have:

```
with x1 ,count(x2) as x3
```

Your aggregation of `count(x2)` is per `x1`. So per distinct x1 node, the count of the associated x2 nodes.

In your second query, the variables are different, and so the grouping key is different:

```
with x1 ,x2, count(x2) as x3
```

Per x1 and x2, what is the count of that particular x2? If there were multiple rows with the same `x1` and `x2` nodes, then you might have some count > 1. But if there was only one row for that particular `x1` and `x2` nodes, then the count would be 1.

EDIT

If you want to get the counts of x2 per x1, and after that continue to work with x2 nodes, then you will need to collect(x2) at the same time as you count(x2) (since it's an aggregation term, it isn't part of the grouping key). Then you can UNWIND the list back to rows.

Your query doesn't actually use x2 nodes so we really don't have to do anything with them, but I'll show the technique anyway:

```
Match (x1:A) 
with x1 
optional Match (x1)-[:A_B]-(x2:B) 
with x1 , collect(x2) as nodes, count(x2) as x3 
where x1.foo= 'bar' and (x3 = 1) 
UNWIND nodes as x2
return DISTINCT x1 as A 
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: then how we can write the query where we can do some operations on x2 ? As for that we need to pass x2 using WITH

Comment: Updated with info on how to do this.